# How to check if a named capture group exists?

Tags: c#, regex

In my regex the pattern is something like this:

```
@"Something\(\d+, ""(.+)""(, .{1,5}, \d+, (?<somename>\d+)?\),"
```

So I would like to know if `<somename>` exists. If it was a normal capture group, I could just check if the capture groups are greater than the number of groups without that/those capture group(s), but I don't have the option here.

Could anyone help me find a way round this? I don't need it to be efficient, it's just for a one-time program that's used for sorting, so I don't mind if it takes a bit to run. It's not going to be for public code.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hchbwda2.aspx):

> If groupname is not the name of a capturing group in the collection,
>   or if groupname is the name of a capturing group that has not been
>   matched in the input string, the method returns a Group object whose
>   Group.Success property is false and whose Group.Value property is
>   String.Empty.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Something\(\d+, ""(.+)""(, .{1,5}, \d+, (?<somename>\d+)?\),");
var match = regex.Match(input);
var group = match.Groups["somename"];
bool exists = group.Success;
```

Comment: I was expecting an IndexOutOfRangeException. Should've tried it. Stupid. Thanks! +1.