# How to know which option in Regex was matched?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex that match multiple option.

E.g. `^0x[\da-fA-F]+|-?\d+$` -- a Regex for Match either decimal or hex literals

Is there an option to know which option was eventually match the pattern?

so for...

- `-10` - the decimal option was matched
- `0x1Af` - the hex option was matched

Comment: Your regex does not match any string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: fixed the Regex.. now the example works

Comment: But it is still wrong as each part is only anchored on one side. You meant to use `^(?:0x[\da-fA-F]+|-?\d+)$`. However, to solve your issue, add capturing groups, `^(?:(0x[\da-fA-F]+)|(-?\d+))$` and check if there `.Success` property is true.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It would be nice if you be more clear on your statement.. but anyhow, it is not my question - that Regex is just an example.

Comment: split this in groups.. eg ^(0x[\da-fA-F]+)|(-?\d+$)
Now you can see which group matches which

Comment: Why don't you use two separate regexes to verify which matched? E.g. (pseudocode) `if (hexRegex.isMatch(text)) itsHex(); else if (decRegex.isMatch()) itsDec()` ?

Comment: BTW, [here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389340/how-to-check-if-a-named-capture-group-exists) showing how to check `Group.Success` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you meant this regex:

```
^(?:-?\d+|0x[\da-fA-F]+)$
```

with the start and end anchors *not* part of the alternatives.

You can capture the different alternatives:

```
^(?:(-?\d+)|(0x[\da-fA-F]+))$
```

Now you just need to check if a group is not null. If it matches the first alternative, group 1 will be non-null. If it matches the second alternative, group 2 will be non-null:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(...);
if (m.Groups[1] != null) {
    // first alternative matched!
} else if (m.Groups[2] != null) {
    // second alternative matched!
}
```

You can also name your groups to make your code more readable:

```
^(?:(?<decimal>-?\d+)|(?<hex>0x[\da-fA-F]+))$
```

Now you should check for `m.Groups["decimal"]` and `m.Groups["hex"]`.

Comment: Thanks - this is an elegant way to know which option by using groups. The Regex itself is not the real question here (just an example)...

Comment: I'd change the nullchecks to not-nullchecks for consistency, as the way you put it has it crossed (if `m.Groups[1]` is `null`, it means that this is not what we are looking for, right?)

Comment: _"so you can't use this regex to determine what base a number is in"_ If the expected hex string always starts with `0x`, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You can also use named groups in regular expression.

Comment: @Asunez Yep, that's indeed more intuitive.